# Java Sockets - Clients receiving different Objects

Tags: java, sockets, stream

So I want to make a card game in Java using Sockets. I have this "PlayerState" object who keeps all the players who are in Lobby or are ready to play. The problem is even if the server send the same object for all clients, all clients receive a different object with incorrect data... Let me explain

So this is the Method in the SERVER which send the Object:

```
private void sendToAll(PlayersState playersState){
    resetLists(playersState.getLobbyPlayers(),playersState.getReadyPlayer());
    Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream writer = (ObjectOutputStream) it.next();
            writer.writeObject(playersState);
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println(playersState.getLobbyPlayers());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
}
```

this is the Method in CLIENT which recieves the Object

```
private void whileChatting() throws IOException {
        sendMessage("&nume"+nume);
        do {
            try {
                Object object = input.readObject();

                if(object instanceof String)
                    showMessage("\n" + (String) object);

                else if(object instanceof PlayersState){
                    System.out.println(((PlayersState) object).getLobbyPlayers());
                    PlayersState actualPlayerState = new PlayersState();
                    actualPlayerState.setReadyPlayer(((PlayersState) object).getReadyPlayer());
                    actualPlayerState.setLobbyPlayers(((PlayersState) object).getLobbyPlayers());
                    resetLists(actualPlayerState.getLobbyPlayers(),actualPlayerState.getReadyPlayer());
                }

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException var2) {
                showMessage("Unknown data received!");
            }
        } while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
    }
```

And this is the Object(available in both CLIENT and SERVER)

```
package sample;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class PlayersState implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;
    private List<String> LobbyPlayers;
    private List<String> ReadyPlayer;

    public PlayersState(){
        LobbyPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
        ReadyPlayer = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void removeFrom(String name, List<String> list){
        if(list.contains(name))
            list.remove(name);
    }

    public void addTo(String name, List<String> list){
        list.add(name);
    }

    public List<String> getLobbyPlayers() {
        return LobbyPlayers;
    }

    public void setLobbyPlayers(List<String> lobbyPlayers) {
        LobbyPlayers = lobbyPlayers;
    }

    public List<String> getReadyPlayer() {
        return ReadyPlayer;
    }

    public void setReadyPlayer(List<String> readyPlayer) {
        ReadyPlayer = readyPlayer;
    }
}
```

If i open 3 Clients one after one let's say user1 user2 and user3 the output from the println from SERVER would be:

```
[user1, user2, user3]
[user1, user2, user3]
[user1, user2, user3]
```

Up here all is normal. But this is what clients receive:

Client 1(user1):

```
[user1]
[user1]
[user1]
```

Client 2(user2)

```
[user1,user2]
[user1,user2]
```

Client 3(user3)

```
[user1,user2,user3]
```

Why does clients not receive all the same data?

Comment: Does the `playersState` has be changed when the server send it to client.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Are you using multiple threads in the server? If so, how are you synchronizing access to the `PlayersState` instance?

Comment: yes, i use multiple threads but this is my first project of this kind and i dont know how to syncronize

Answer (score -1):

The `PlayersState` is not a mutable class,so you should synchronized it at multiple-thread.like this:

```
tresetLists(playersState.getLobbyPlayers(),playersState.getReadyPlayer());
    Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();

    byte[] sendBytes=null;
    synchronized (playersState) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(playersState);
        sendBytes = bos.toByteArray();
        oos.close();
    }

    while (it.hasNext())
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream writer = (ObjectOutputStream) it.next();
            writer.write(sendBytes);
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println(playersState.getLobbyPlayers());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
```

in the above code,for performance and reduce the hold time of lock, we lock `playersState` and just serial the it into `sendBytes` array once.
Of course,you should synchronize the `playersState` at anytime,like invoke the `getLobbyPlayers` and `getReadyPlayer` on other thread.

Comment: where should i add the lock variable?

Comment: I update my answer,and don't use the `ReentrantLock`,just use the `synchronized`.When you access a same instance of `PlayersState`, you should synchronize it.

Comment: now the server gives me an EOFException

java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2917)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1502)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
 at sample.Main$newClient.run(Main.java:258)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: `PlayerState` is definitely mutable. Perhaps you meant to write "...is not an *immutable* class..." Also, I don't see any evidence of threading at all in the OPs code, so I'm not sure how you've concluded it's a synchronization issue.

Comment: so i tried to change the whole object with a simple Map<String, List<String>> and the result is the same...